# Placemark kml info not showing in iOS version of Google Earth

Tags: ios, kml, google-earth

The information for placemarks that I have created in a kml file does
not show on the iPad. The window opens up, but there is no content. It
has worked in the past and it works fine in Google Earth for Windows
and Android. I have a feeling that this might be an issue with Google
Earth on the iPad more than a kml issue.

Here is the file if anybody is interested in taking a look:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/18240150/GoogleEarthAirports30Apr12.kml

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your KML looks good (actually, it's very nicely done; the airports look and behave great):

- Visual desk check in a text editor and it looks good
- Loaded in Google Earth without problems (confirms the behavior you saw)
- Also there is an [Interactive KML Parser](https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/reference/interface_g_e_plugin) available online - your KML ran through the parse without errors

Your suspicion that the root cause of your problem lies with the iPad or Google Earth on the iPad appears to be correct. I don't have an iPad, so I can't test that, but knowing that an independent test had similar results at least helps to pinpoint the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a work around for this problem.

Prepare a KML file with NetworkLink tag referring to your ***remote*** KML file and download the file.
Then description rendering works well even on iOS5.
"Remote", which means a file places at a server like "http://example.com/sample.kml", is important. Local files like a file in a .kmz file don't work currently.